# Cypress test with Debounce input

Tags: reactjs, cypress

Please some help.

I have a debounced handleChange function to an input.
The debounced function is:

```
const useDebounce = (func, timeout = 500) => {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}

export default useDebounce
```

And handler is:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    onData({ name: e.target.name, value: e.target.value });
};
const debouncedHandleChange = useDebounce((e) => handleChange(e), 700);
```

The debounce function is fetching data from an API. If i use the browser, it's work fine.

Note: I used in the same code the debounce function of lodash and it's ok, but I should use the useDebounce function.

The cypress test is:

```
describe('Testing autoload PreForm information [Desktop]', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
  cy.loadingCucaCorpContact();
      cy.visit('/');
      cy.setViewportXL();
  });

  it('should display autoloaded information', () => {
      cy.findAllByText('Despacho y retiro').click();
      cy.findAllByText('No ha llegado mi producto').click();
      cy.get('[data-cy=inputrutNotReceived]').type('11111111-1');
      cy.get('[data-cy=inputorderIdNotReceived]').type('777777777');
      cy.contains(
          'Lo sentimos, estamos presentando algunas dificultades, vuelve a intentarlo dentro de un momento',
          { timeout: 5000 }
    );
  });
});
```

Well, the test is not succeded because isn't calling the API.
I used examples like:

```
cy.wait(6000)
...
cy.clock()
cy.tick(500)
...
cy.get('[data-cy=inputorderIdNotReceived]').type('777777777').trigger('change);
```

... and still doesn't work

Any idea?

*Best regards*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debounce is always a bit mind-boggling, but I notice you have sent in `700ms` in the app but in the test you tick for just `500ms`.

First, try with `cy.tick(710)`.

If that does not work, remove the `cy.clock()` and `cy.tick()` as these actually stop the debounce from firing (`setTimout()` is effectively frozen by these commands).

**React hooks and cy.wait(0)**

`useDebounce` looks like it's a custom hook, so the next thing to try is adding `cy.wait(0)` to release the JS thread and allow React hooks to process.

```js
cy.findAllByText('Despacho y retiro').click();
cy.findAllByText('No ha llegado mi producto').click();

cy.get('[data-cy=inputrutNotReceived]').type('11111111-1');
cy.wait(0)

cy.get('[data-cy=inputorderIdNotReceived]').type('777777777');
cy.wait(0)

cy.contains('Lo sentimos', { timeout: 5000 })
```

**.type() delay option**

Third option, Cypress `.type()` has a delay option that may be useful, but it's between keypresses, but debounce is to delay sending the whole string to the API.

In any case, it's worth a try because complicated handler may not pick up keys entered by Cypress at the default rate of 10ms.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=inputrutNotReceived]').type('11111111-1', {delay: 100});
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! The delay option on type command is the correct way.

Comment: As I understand it the contains() and get()s have a default delay of 4 seconds. So any debounce below 1 second should not affect the test at all. So are you saying that cypress blocks other async tasks from completing without calling wait(0)? That would be extremely annoying ^^

Comment: The command timeout of 4 seconds is just how long the command waits overall for the expected condition to occur. This problem seems to be about coordinating the test inputting a character and the app responding to the character entry. It may be exacerbated by the debounce being implemented in a hook, which is React fiber based and involves some "context switching" code to run.